# centos free memory stats

Tags: centos, memory

I was curious to know about my 512mb ram vps and I checked 
my centos vps with the 'top' command

[image]

Apparently out of there is like ~20Mb of free ram. Is that an issue?
This vps has been running for like 6 months, should I clear ram
cache or that won't solve anything.
I saw a pretty similiar stuff of another vps's screenshot whereas he
has 1G of ram and 0.9G were used like in my case.

A single website runs on this website and it is pretty much static
(no mysql). Just xml encoding/decoding when a visitor visits the
page. I imagine installing mysql or other packages would kill the ram?

I'm a beginner so I apologize in advance for any silly question I
might have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem, memory not in use is memory to no use... Linux will use free RAM to cache disk. Once that RAM gets needed for any process the amount used for cache will decrease.

You could also study the output of 'free' which will show you free RAM both with and without buffer/cache consideration.